# (really) Simple percentage calculation with currency conversion

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a pretty simple question, I'm afraid I have been out of math-land for too long!

We have two currencies, the U.S. dollar and the rupee.

`$1 us dollar = .015 rupees` (just an example, probably no where near the actual conversion).

Let's say I have $100,000$ rupees, how do I figure out the new value of my rupees if the value raises to be equal to the U.S. dollar ($1 U.S. dollar = 1 rupee)

Comment: If you have $r$ rupees, and each rupee is worth $x$ dollars, then you have $rx$ dollars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply the number of rupees by the value in dollars of one rupee.

If the problem is that your conversion "goes the other way" (that is, you have something like 1 US dollar = 0.75 rupees, then "solve" for how many dollars equals one rupee first:
\begin{align*}
1\text{ dollars} &= 0.75\text{ rupees}\\
\frac{1}{0.75} \text{ dollars} &= \frac{0.75}{0.75} \text{ rupees}\\
\frac{4}{3}\text{ dollars} &= 1\text{ rupees.}
\end{align*}
and then you can just multiply the number of rupees by $\frac{4}{3}$ to get the number of dollars.

Comment: thank you! i'd up-vote but no reputation yet...